# How to solve the error "Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have problem trying implement hibernate in my project.
I development my project in Java with Maven And Spring, but when i try to run my project, not work.
Please help me whit this error, i do'nt lnow how to solve this.
Or please tell me whats go wron

```
15:03:39.224 [main] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final-redhat-2
15:03:39.232 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5bcea91b: defining beans [dataSource,hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory,SesionDAO]; root of factory hierarchy
15:03:39.232 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at rest.test.main(test.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeResolutionHelper.<init>(TypeResolutionHelper.java:21)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more
```

Please help me whit this issue.

Comment: Have you checked your `pom.xml` ? You have missed one of the `dependency`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
  <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The scope of the dependency needs to be compile. If it is not provided by your application server.